# Jquery animate with queue function execute only once

Tags: jquery, queue, jquery-animate

I have a box, when I click on it, I want the box animate first and then return it to original position, the code:

```
$('#test').click(function () {    //#test is the box
        var o ={       //remember the original position
            "x":"0px",
            "y":"0px"           
        }

        $(this).animate({
            "left": "15px",
            "top": "15px"           
        }).queue(function () { //afte execute the animate, return to its origin position
            $(this).css({  
                'left': o.x,
                'top': o.y
            })               
        })
    })
```

but problem is ,this effect could only execute once, when I click it on the second time, it never execute, so why this happened? how can I solve the problem?

here is the only [example](http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/f5ZUJ/):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KiroSora09's answer is probably simpler, but the proper way to use queued functions is to remove the function from the queue after executing it like this:

```
$('#test').click(function () {    //#test is the box
    var o ={       //remember the original position
        "x":"0px",
        "y":"0px"           
    }

    $(this).animate({
        "left": "15px",
        "top": "15px"           
    }).queue(function(next) { //after execute the animate, return to its origin position
        $(this).css({  
            'left': o.x,
            'top': o.y
        })               
        next();
    });
})​;
```

or like this:

```
$('#test').click(function () {    //#test is the box
    var o ={       //remember the original position
        "x":"0px",
        "y":"0px"           
    }

    $(this).animate({
        "left": "15px",
        "top": "15px"           
    }).queue(function() { //after execute the animate, return to its origin position
        $(this).css({  
            'left': o.x,
            'top': o.y
        }).dequeue();
    });
})​;
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/qM2CJ/

Documentation on `.queue(fn)` is [here](http://api.jquery.com/queue/).

Answer (score 1):

Please try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/79Nqp/1/) demo

I used a callback instead. I hope i understood it right.

Edit:

Here is the javascript code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#test').click(function() {
        var o = {
            "x": "0px",
            "y": "0px"
        }

        $(this).animate({
            "left": "15px",
            "top": "15px"
        }, function() {
            $(this).css({
                'left': o.x,
                'top': o.y
            })
        });
    })
})​
```

Comment: Best to put your code solution pasted into your answer so people don't have to go to an external site to see it.